# Javafx NavBar Issue

Tags: java, javafx, navigation

I've been using javafx for the GUI in one of my projects.  It is supposed to have capabilities of adding entries, deleting entries, viewing entries, modifying entries, and searching through the entries.  I've accomplished all these things, and have been trying to make the GUI cleaner, by putting a navbar at the top while having the rest of the GUI change with respect to what particular task is at hand.  However, it has been displaying some peculiar behaviors(at best) that I've been unable to fix.

This is the relevant section of code:

```
private static Scene makeScene(Stage primaryStage, BorderPane searchRoot, BorderPane addRoot, BorderPane viewRoot){
    final Scene[] scene = {null};
    final Scene searchScene;
    final Scene addScene;
    final Scene viewScene;

    final int WIDTH = 500;
    final int HEIGHT = 600;

    HBox navBar = new HBox(15);
    Button searchButton = new Button("Search People");
    Button addButton    = new Button("Add Person");
    Button viewButton   = new Button("View People");

    navBar.getChildren().addAll(searchButton, addButton, viewButton);
    navBar.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    navBar.setPrefHeight(42);
    searchRoot.setTop(navBar);
    addRoot.setTop(navBar);
    viewRoot.setTop(navBar);

    searchScene = new Scene(searchRoot, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    addScene    = new Scene(addRoot,    WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    viewScene   = new Scene(viewRoot,   WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    scene[0] = viewScene;

    searchButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println("Search Button Pressed");
        scene[0] = searchScene;
        primaryStage.setScene(scene[0]);
    });
    addButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println("Add Button Pressed");
        scene[0] = addScene;
        primaryStage.setScene(scene[0]);
    });
    viewButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println("Soup");
        scene[0] = viewScene;
        primaryStage.setScene(scene[0]);
    });

    return scene[0];
}
```

Which is being called in this manner:

```
    primaryStage.setScene(makeScene(primaryStage, searchRoot, addRoot, viewRoot));
    primaryStage.show();
```

When any button on the navBar is pressed, it does switch to the proper panel, but the navBar itself disappears, making further navigation impossible.  My best guess as to why this is happening is because the navBar 'lives' inside of what it is trying to change, but I'm not sure about that.  I would appreciate it were someone to tell me both why this is not working as I had intended, as well as suggestions as to how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is more or less correct. `primaryStage.setScene(...)` will replace the entire content of the stage. In addition, a node can only have a single parent node, so the behavior is undefined when you set the `navBar` to the top of three different `BorderPane`s. (I *think* it will just end up only appearing in the last one, `viewRoot`, but that is entirely implementation dependent.)

I recommend you refactor this: use a `BorderPane` as the root of the (one and only) `Scene`. Put the nav bar in the top of the border pane, and change the contents by calling `setCenter(...)` on the border pane, passing in either `searchRoot`, `addRoot`, or `viewRoot` as appropriate.

Something like:

```
private static void makeScene(Stage primaryStage, Node searchRoot, Node addRoot, Node viewRoot){

    final int WIDTH = 500;
    final int HEIGHT = 600;

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

    final Scene scene = new Scene(root, WIDTH, HEIGHT);


    HBox navBar = new HBox(15);
    Button searchButton = new Button("Search People");
    Button addButton    = new Button("Add Person");
    Button viewButton   = new Button("View People");

    navBar.getChildren().addAll(searchButton, addButton, viewButton);
    navBar.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    navBar.setPrefHeight(42);

    root.setTop(navBar);

    searchButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println("Search Button Pressed");
        root.setCenter(searchRoot);
    });
    addButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println("Add Button Pressed");
        root.setCenter(addRoot);
    });
    viewButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println("Soup");
        root.setCenter(viewRoot);
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
}
```